# Issue with scanf() in a while loop

Tags: c, scanf

I'm pretty new to C, I am trying to code a simple chatroom and I am having trouble with the scanf() function. Here is the relevant code:

```
while(1)
{   
    printf("2");

    //Now sending message to server
    bzero(buffer, 256);
    printf("3");
    scanf("%255s", buffer);
    printf("3");
    n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0)
    {   
        perror("Error writing to socket");
        exit(1);
    }   

    printf("3");
    //Print server response
    bzero(buffer, 256);
    n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
    if (n < 0)
    {   
        perror("Error reading from socket");
        exit(1);
    }   

    printf("4");
    printf("I got sent %s\n", buffer);
}   
return 0;
```

The first time through it sends the message to the server and receives a message back. However, the second time it gets hung on the scanf statement as if the scanf statement won't stop reading when it receives a newline character. Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's hung on the `scanf`? What if you use `printf("3\n")` instead of `printf("3")`? Do you see the `3` then? If you're using `printf` as a debug trace, you need to flush the output on every `printf`. Terminating each `printf` string with `\n` will do that for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just added the \n at the end of every printf statement and now I see that it's getting hung up in the part where it's reading back from the server.

Comment: As an aside, never use `scanf`. It's inherently unsafe and has been deprecated. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @EdS. Who said `scanf` is deprecated